# How to match a particular word in a string that isn't surrounded by quote marks?

Tags: javascript, regex

As an example I have this string: aaa bbb "aaa bbb ccc" bbb "ddd"

I want to match bbb, but only if it's not inside quotation marks using regex.

Anyone have an idea?

**UPDATE**

I suppose I should have been more specific, I'll amend my example:

Say I have an html tag, I wish to grab an attribute and its value:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" myattr="myvalue" name="myattr test" />
```

I need to match the word's myattr and myvalue, but ONLY when myattr is not surrounded by quotes and when myvalue is definitely myattr's value.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use the getAtributeValue method of the input nodes?

Comment: @missingno Yes, because the attribute is html5 and therefore not standard across all browsers. I need to do this so I can use JS to create something similar for the browsers which don't support the attribute :)

Comment: How are you getting the contents of the html tag?

Comment: @ErikE I'm using jQuery: $(this).parent().html(); and then using regex to find the correct tag.

Comment: @Nathan: getAttributeValue should also work on nonstandard attributes, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you just use `attr('myattr')` on your `input` element?

See [an example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qtc2/1/);

Also, I suggest looking into the following:

- The [HTML 5 Shim](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/) (a.k.a. "HTML 5 Shiv" - [see the history](http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/))
- [HTML 5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/).
- [Using HTML5 Semantic Elements Today](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/03/22/using-html5-semantic-elements-today/)

Why reinvent the wheel when others have code ready for you to use?

Comment: Huh...I wasn't aware of createElement allowing it to be accessed by attr() I'm not using html5shiv because it doesn't help me here since i'm making support for <input type="number">

Comment: Actually, the `createelement` part was mistakenly left in. But it seems that expandos can be accesses by jQuery using `attr`.

Comment: @Nathan Also check out the boilerplate link!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: "[^b"]*(bbb)[^"]*" ...

Answer (score 0):

Match either a quoted passage, or `bbb`, then check what you got.

```
var s = 'aaa bbb "aaa bbb ccc" bbb "ddd"';

var s = s.replace(/("[^"]*"|bbb)/g, function(m){
    if (m == 'bbb') {
        return "xxx";
    } else {
        return m;
    }
});

alert(s);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Q4gB8/

(If `bbb` is unknown (a regular expression in itself), you can check for the quotation marks instead.)